# Problems in using Keytool

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I'm trying to generate the certificate for developing applications with integration with facebook, using the keytool command. I put the command correctly, the password is requested (I'm putting 'android', which I believe is correct) and then when I press the button 'enter', the system is making a beep three times and appears some strange characters at the command prompt.

It is the first time I generate the certificate and am not sure if I'm doing the right way. The command that I am applying is:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\MyUser\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Someone has had the same situation?

Comment: I am having the same problem on OSX. Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: I dont know why, but I just tried again someday and dont got any problems! I do not know what I changed, but for some reason, it's working now. Sorry for not getting help.

Answer (score 3):

You're not running the full command. From the [google developers page](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#creating-android-api-keys) (Note the `-list -v`):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore path-to-keystore -list -v
```

I know this is an old topic, but I just spent ~20 minutes googling my "problem". Hopefully this spares someone the time and frustration.

Comment: I was missing the ```-list``` part. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Option -exportcert is for getting .cer publickey file from kekeystore public and private key file.

for generating certificate use -genkey option with keytool.

keytool -genkey -alias selfsigned -keyalg RSA -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity 365

and follow instructions on command line. Above command gives you keypair.

Now use -export to get public key from above keypair file. Then use -import option to import the public key file to truststores, you have to import file to all systems which you want to trust selfsigned.jks file.

Check this oracle page. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html